# Polygon not drawn in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, html, jquery

I am trying to get some polygon features drawn on my map. point features are working fine. even the coordinates of my polygon are correct, i draw them as point features on my map to check that.

i am using the latest version of openlayers (3.2 i guess).

here the code i am using for populating the polygons:

```
mapView = new ol.View({
      center: [15.438445,47.071028],
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      zoom: 17
    });

            // MAP ERSTELLEN
            map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Group({
          'title': 'Basis',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'Bing',
                        type: 'base',
                        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
                        key:
        'my key here ..',
                        imagerySet: 'Road'
                        }),
                    })
          ]
        }),
        window.overlayGroup
      ],
      view: mapView
            });
    sehenswuerdigkeitLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: 'Sehenswürdigkeiten',
            type: 'overlay',
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            source: new ol.source.Vector()
        });
```

....

```
  var polygonGeometry = new ol.geom.Polygon();
          var coordinates = [];

          console.log(geoJson.coordinates);
          $.each(geoJson.coordinates, function(i, polyCoordsArr) {

            $.each(polyCoordsArr, function(i2, polyCoords) {
              if (polyCoords.length == 0) {
                return true;
              }

              var geschaeftFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
                  [polyCoords[1],polyCoords[0]]
                )
              });
              sehenswuerdigkeitLayer.getSource().addFeature(geschaeftFeature);

              coordinates.push([polyCoords[1],polyCoords[0]]);
            });
          });

          console.log(coordinates);



          polygonGeometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);
          sehenswuerdigkeitFeature.setGeometry(polygonGeometry);
sehenswuerdigkeitLayer.getSource().addFeature(sehenswuerdigkeitFeature);
```

the loops are neccessary because i get those coordinates from my database, also i have to switch those coordinates since openlayers use [longitude,latitude] and not [latitude, longitude] as point.

the result of my code gives following object output:

[image: coordinates object]

here you can see that the points / coordinates of my polygon are valid (visible as blue circles, ignore the green round circles, thats just other features)

[image: map preview with polygon coordinates displayed as point feature]